# MySQLで多対多の関係で片方をuniqueにしたい

Tags: mysql

UserとLanguageというEntityとuser_languagesという関係データベースが存在するとして、Userは複数のLanguageを持っているとし、Languageは複数のUserに持たれているとします。

```
user
    id
    languages
language
    id
    name <- 同じnameのエントリーが複数追加されてしまう。
user_language
    user_id
    language_id
```

このような場合の`language`のある要素(`name`)の重複をなくすようなオプションはありますでしょうか。つまり別の`user`が持っている`language`を登録した時にすでにその`language`が`languages`テーブルに存在するときに`user_language`にそのすでに存在する`language`の`id`を登録し、`languages`テーブルにはインサートしないようにしたいです。`INSERT INTO "languages" ("name") VALUES ('JPN');`を入力した時にした時に重複を避けることは可能でしょうか。
`name`に`unique`を指定するとエラーがでてしまいました。

```
Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'ENG' for key 'name'
```

ちなみに`languages`のスキーマは下記のようになっています。

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`name`には`index:idx_name_code`を設定しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `INSERT INTO "languages" ("name") VALUES ('JPN');`を入力した時にした時に重複を避けることは可能でしょうか。

`UNIQUE`制約を指定するのであれば、

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO "languages" ("name") VALUES ('JPN');
```

でよいのでは。なおこの場合`LAST_INSERT_ID()`等は使用できなくなりますので、`SELECT`で該当の`language.id`を調べる必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、結局`user_languages`テーブルに関連を挿入しなければならないので、1つずつ`name`で`SELECT`して重複を調べてから挿入したほうがいいかもしれませんね。

Comment: @zousan まあ結局プログラムの組み方次第という面が大きいのですが、`INSERT IGNORE`→`SELECT`は一ステートメントで確実にレコードが作成できるので`SELECT`→`INSERT`よりロックの設計が多少楽になるというメリットはあります。